# How to reload angularjs scope data without rerendering bound view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I've got a small problem. I have a bootstrap tabset within an angularjs app. The tabs are partially generated from ng-repeat and contain data, that is bound to the scope.

Basically, within the controller:

```
$scope.data = { ... }  // Loaded from a factory
```

Now, when I reload this data (by replacing the old one with the new one) the tabset will be rebuilt by ng-repeat and the view will automatically switch to the first tab.

Is there a way to replace the data in scope without rebuilding everything in the view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't explicit about the specific data and which of it is used in what ways.
So this will have to be a general answer:

Try to update only the bits that actually changed.
For example do not replace whole objects or arrays, but only updated properties or indices that actually changed. That way only the relevant parts of the GUI will update.

If you must replace objects, you can still help angular keep the connection between objects in the model and dom elements for ng-repeat if you use "track by" in the expression (which is possible only if the element has some unique id that you can use for that).

Another option: Use one time binding for the parts that should change only exactly once when the data is first loaded: See the section "One-time binding" in https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression

Comment: Yaaa... Thats not that easy. I can't refresh just one part, as the hole thing might have changed. And one-time-binding would disable **all** further updates for the contained data - right?

Comment: Yes, all updates would be disabled with one time binding.

Oh and what would possibly also help: If you can't avoid having new objects (as opposed to leave unchanged objects alone), then use "track by" in any ng-repeat, so that angular can know which object belongs to which dom element and avoid rebuilding tabs.